# Remove or rename play store package so I can republish

Tags: android, google-play

I lost the key to publish my app in a hard drive malfunction, now I want to reupload it, but the package name is already taken by my now abandoned, unpublished app.  Can I change the name of that package somehow?  Or delete rather than just unpublish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ali Ahsan informed, you cannot delete it. But, you can try reaching out to Google Play Support and see if they can help you. As such chances are less. But, no harm in giving it a shot.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer#topic=3450769

Also,from what I know, you need to justify the reason and provide details of your ownership. In future, you can try using Google App signing. In that way, you can retrieve your key, even if you lose it.  App signing by Google Play makes it possible to request a reset to your upload key

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

> Can I change the name of that package somehow?

You can change the package name in android studio and upload as a new app

> Delete rather than just unpublish?

You can't delete the app from google play console